# socket.io callbacks

Tags: javascript, node.js, callback

I have the following code:

```
  client.keys("key_"+id, function (err, replies){
      if (replies.length > 0){
        client.sunion(replies,function (err, replies){
          {...}
        });
      }else{...}
     });
```

below I have this function

```
pg.connect(conString, function(err, client) {some code});
```

But I  want execute `pg.connect`  instead of `...` in first piece of code.
How best to do to avoid copying code and memory leaks, `pg.connect` function will be the same in all `{...}`.

With copying code this will be look like:

```
    client.keys("key_"+id, function (err, replies){
      if (replies.length > 0){
        client.sunion(replies,function (err, replies){
          pg.connect(conString, function(err, client) {some code});
        });
      }else{pg.connect(conString, function(err, client) {some code});}
     });
```

Answer (score 1):

Remember that you are working with JavaScript and can define little helper functions to reduce your typing...

```
function withConnect( callback ) {
    return pg.connect( conString, callback );
}
```

for instance will save you some time... But what if the error handler is always the same?

```
function withConnect( callback ) {
    return pg.connect( conString, function( err, client ) {
        if ( err ) {
           handleError( err );
        }
        // we might still want something special on errors...
        callback.apply( this, arguments );
    }
 }
```

You could even abstract simple insert/update style queries this way.

Answer (score 0):

You can try (if the "some code" sections are the same):

```
function connectFunc() {
    return function (err){
       pg.connect(conString, function(err, client) {some code});
    };
}

client.keys("key_"+id, function (err, replies){
    if (replies.length > 0){
        client.sunion(replies, connectFunc());
    } else { connectFunc()(err)}
});
```

Or, if the "some code" varies:

```
function connectFunc(some_code) {
    return function (err){
       pg.connect(conString, function(err, client) {some_code();});
    };
}

client.keys("key_"+id, function (err, replies){
    if (replies.length > 0){
        client.sunion(replies, connectFunc(function(){some code}));
    } else { connectFunc(function(){some other code})(err)}
});
```